# Selenium full webpage screenshot

Tags: c#, selenium

How to take screenshot of full webpage in selenium with c#.
Noksa package doesn't have .ToBitmap() function as suggested in many videos.

Answer (score 0):

Here is snippet from the [docs](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/browser/windows/#takescreenshot)

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

var driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.example.com");
Screenshot screenshot = (driver as ITakesScreenshot).GetScreenshot();
screenshot.SaveAsFile("screenshot.png", ScreenshotImageFormat.Png); // Format values are Bmp, Gif, Jpeg, Png, Tiff
```

Answer (score 0):

I use noksa for full screen screenshots and I'm seeing the ToBitMap(); included. It comes with the imagemagick version that noksa installs. This is the code I have that works. Granted I havent used a bitmap before so I dont know if this bitmap created here will work for what you want, but I didnt get any error when creating it. I used a google terms page so you can see the quality of the screenshot.

```
        public static  void Scraps()
        {
            //Initiate Browser Instance
            IWebDriver driver = InitBrowser("chrome");

            //Go to Page of google terms
            driver.Url = "https://www.google.com/intl/en_ZZ/policies/terms/archive/20070416/";

            //Declare VCD which combines the various screenshots taken into one
            VerticalCombineDecorator vcd = new VerticalCombineDecorator(new ScreenshotMaker());

            //Declare Destination Folder
            string folder = @"C:\Users\User\Documents\test" + ".png";

            //Take Screenshot and save 
        driver.TakeScreenshot(vcd).ToMagickImage().Write(string.Format(folder), ImageMagick.MagickFormat.Png);

            //Take Screenshot and Create Bitmap
            System.Drawing.Bitmap Screenshot = driver.TakeScreenshot(vcd).ToMagickImage().ToBitmap();
            driver.Quit();

        }
```

Comment: It's not working same issue .ToBitmap